# What is if 'admin' in request.path

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I followed YouTube Django E-commerce video, I did exactly the same as the tutorial.

But I found some difficulty in certain code.

CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.PY

```
from .models import cart,cartitem
from .views import getcartid

def counter(request):
    cart_counter=0  
    **if 'admin' in request.path:**
        return {}
    else:
        try:
            cart1=cart.objects.filter(cartid=getcartid(request))     
            cart_items=cartitem.objects.all().filter(basket=cart1[:1])     from 1
            for cart_item in cart_items:
                cart_counter += cart_item.quantity
        except cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart_counter=0
    return dict(cart_counter=cart_counter)
```

Can someone explain for me what is if 'admin' in request.path, then return {}?

Comment: It checks if the path, for example `/foo/bar/admin/qux`, contains `admin`. But it looks like horribe code design since for example the url could be `badminton`, and then it thus exports nothing to the context.

Answer (score 0):

It check that the requested user is an admin or not:
you can check by this code:

```
if request.user.is_admin or is_staff or is_superuser from this you can check one thing and return blank dict
```